# Parse text/xml response in spring resttemplate exchange method

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, java-ee-8

I'm consuming a http endpoint which is returns a text/xml content as the response. It should return a number as the response within xml document. How do I parse it.

Here is the response when I consume the endpoint using postman.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<int xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">2</int>
```

When I try as below, it gives me an error.

```
Integer originalResponse = REST_TEMPLATE.exchange(new URI(PropertyConfig.endPointUrl), HttpMethod.POST, httpEntity, Integer.class).getBody();
```

but if I set the return type as String, It gives me the xml as a plain text. I need get the number which is within the  tags as the result.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You get XML not an integer. Create a wrapper object, then extract the int from the wrapper object.

Comment: Could you please give me an example? How do I write a wrapper object for this?